# When using an upload photo script, it won't rename the file

Tags: php

I'm using a photo upload script for my social network and it won't work, here's the code:

Upload.php

```
<style>
.sucess{
color:#088A08;
}
.error{
color:red;
}
</style>

<?php
$file_exts = array("jpg", "bmp", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$upload_exts = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)
&& in_array($upload_exts, $file_exts))
{
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
// Enter your path to upload file here
if (file_exists("profile_pictures/" .
$_FILES["file"]["name"]))
{
echo "<div class='error'>"."(".$_FILES["file"]["name"].")".
" already exists. "."</div>";
}
else
{
$my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$new_file_name = $my_id;

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
"profile_pictures/" . $new_file_name);
echo "<div class='sucess'>"."Stored in: " .
"profile_pictures/" . $new_file_name."</div>";
}
}
}
else
{
echo "<div class='error'>Invalid file</div>";
}
?>
```

change_photo.php

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

It just says:

> Upload: A FILE.png Type: image/png Size: 1028.0830078125 kB Temp file:
>   C:\xampp\tmp\phpD21D.tmp
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function
>   cannot be a directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Social Network\upload.php on
>   line 43
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
>   'C:\xampp\tmp\phpD21D.tmp' to 'profile_pictures/' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Social Network\upload.php on line 43 Stored in:
>   profile_pictures/

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that your `$my_id` variable is empty.

Are you using `session_start();` at the very top of your script?

Comment: @LeviJohnson Ouch, you should really be authenticating your user before you process the file-upload.

Comment: Yeah session start is missing there!

Comment: Upload: PewDie Cyrus.png
Type: image/png
Size: 1028.0830078125 kB
Temp file: C:\xampp\tmp\php826C.tmp

Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\Social Network\upload.php on line 39

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Social Network\upload.php on line 43

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php826C.tmp' to 'profile_pictures/' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Social Network\upload.php on line 43
Stored in: profile_pictures/
and i added session_start(); @meda

Comment: `Undefined variable: _SESSION`  you see this? its not set, before you set add `session_start()` again!

Comment: Hopefully he gets it, not sure how to rephrase your answer lol